# Doubt with bounds of the following integral:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

Hi question is as follows: use polar coordinates to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{2y-y^2}}^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy.$$

I'm stuck finding the limits for $r$. So far I've got:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{???} r^2 dr d\theta.$$

How can I proceed from here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you even tried making the substitution? It really clears it up instantly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck finding the limits for $r$... I thought I'd ask the whole question in case I was doing something wrong. :) So far I have $I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{???}r^2drd\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We are integrating over the disk bounded by the circle $x^2+y^2-2y+1=1$, that is, the circle with centre $(0,1)$ and radius $1$. This circle has polar equation $r=2\sin\theta$.

Comment: So does that mean that the limits for are would be $-2sin{\theta}\le r \le 2sin{\theta}$?

Comment: Not quite. The $r$ goes from $0$ to $2\sin\theta$, and then the angle goes from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Aah, okay I see now... Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I did not mention in the solution, but you will be integrating $r^2\,dr\,d\theta$ and end up integrating $8\sin^3\theta\,d\theta$. for $\sin^3\theta$, rewrite as $\sin\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

The bounds on $x$ are $x \in [-\sqrt{2 y-y^2},\sqrt{2 y-y^2}]$.  Note that $2 y-y^2 = 1-(y-1)^2$.  Thus, the boundary of integration is the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$, which has polar representation

$$r^2 \cos^2{\theta} + (r \sin{\theta}-1)^2 = r^2 - 2 r \sin{\theta} + 1=1 \implies r = 2 \sin{\theta}$$  The limits of integration in polar coordinates are $r \in [0,2 \sin{\theta}]$ and $\theta \in [0, \pi]$.  Thus the integral is

$$\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \int_0^{2 \sin{\theta}} dr \, r^2$$

which you should be able to evaluate.

Comment: Is $0\le\theta\le\pi$ because outside of this $r<0$ but since $r$ is a radius $r\ge0$? Also, why can we multiply out the integrands like this? Since the limits aren't independent, isn't this wrong?

Comment: @user72786: you are right re limits on $\theta$.  No, it is not wrong to write the integral out like this - note you evaluate from right to left, so the evaluation of the $r$ integral produces the $\theta$ integral.

Comment: Note that some people say, for instance, $\int dx \ x$, when you might say $\int x\, dx$.

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot more sense now. I've been taught the other convention apparently.